# Any effortless way to create a WCF REST client posting urlformatted requests?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, proxy

This is a duplicate of http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/94503037-9cc4-494d-88af-4e97fcb9cdcc, but I didn't have much success getting fruitful answers over there. :(

I've been trying to find information about getting a nice concrete REST service client (proxy) from ChannelFactory.

As far as I've figured out, you can set attirubtes on a client interface that tells WCF to use XML (DataContract or XmlSerialization) or JSON for responses, and URL formatted HTTP get requests or HTTP post of XML/JSON. [edit from original] And of course providing different binding configurations either programatically or via config. [/edit from original]

What I'd like is to put some attributes on the service interface telling WCF to create an URL formatted POST, without an XML header, and then get a response in XML. (For instance)
[edit from original] And / or providing BCL bindings supporting the follosing [/edit from original]

A dream scenario would be this:

```
public interface IRestClient
{
    [WebInvoke]
    AuthResponse Authorize(
        [HeaderParameter]
        string someHeader,
        string someData, 
        int someInt)
}

// ...

var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel<IRestClient>(); // whatever bindings I'd need for this

var response = client.Authorize("abc", "def", 123);
```

And have client.Authorize actually do

```
HTTP POST /authorize
someHeader: abc
someData=def&someInt=123
```

And deserialize

```
<AuthResponse>
    <Message>Hi there!</Message>
</AuthResponse>
```

As far as I've found out from googling and forum thrashing, there's no way to do this unless you do an immense amount of plumbing, writing interceptors, formatters and god knows what.

The WCF contrib library, the WCF samples et. al. is way too academic and has too much plumbing and/or too little intuitive documentation for me to do this without pain. :)

Any hints to where I can find the simplest possible way to do this?

(And please don't tell me to use `HttpRequest` or `WebClient`, that's why we've got `ChannelFactory`! ;) )

**[update]**

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can understand, a lot of so called REST APIs require URL formatted requests, not Json or Xml.

The WCF interpretation of web based service interfaces reflects `WebGet` and `WebInvoke` attributes on the method definitions to determine how to call each "method" on the "services". (Let me call it method and service for simplicity)

The `WebInvoke` attribute takes a `WebRequestFormat` enum value to determine how to serialize requests. That enum only has Json and Xml.

Seems really silly to me that this is an enum, and not some pointer to a formatter/serializer factory, or even a concrete of said.

So, the question really boils down to the easiest, preferably already implemented, override of the serialization of the requests.

**[/update]**

Comment: Life is too short to over complicate things. There's a reason RestSharp and ASP.NET Web API exists.

Comment: Which makes life more complicated. Would be nicest to have it in the BCL. I'll check out RestSharp. What I want is an easy custombinding combination that does this to a WCF channel.

Comment: @Magnus Don't forget Spring.NET REST client : http://www.springframework.net/rest

Comment: Guys, these are all proprietary protocol dependent frameworks forcing me to write the concrete proxies manually. I could just as well use `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` without much overhead. The question is whether there exists bindings for WCF that does this. For anyone else, please refrain from referencing non-wcf frameworks.

Comment: Another framework [http://nelibur.org/](http://nelibur.org/)

Answer (score 2):

REST does't have a metadata standard. You will, therefore, have to roll your client code yourself using one of the many client side REST toolkits or the basic HTTP APIs in the BCL. You can use WebChannelFactory to define an interafce with WebInvoke, WebGet but you will have to write this yourself or take a copy of the service one.

Generally in REST APIs the API should be dynamically discoverable in terms of URIs as resources should also return relevant URIs and verbs that are applicable for the current state of your interaction or the resource

Comment: I'm aware that REST doesn't have metadata. I'm more than happy to write the interface definition myself, and add the WebGet and WebInvoke attributes. I still hit the wall though, when it comes to the request format. WebInvoke for instance has RequestFormat, but the WebMessageFormat enum only have Json and Xml. I want UrlFormatted, and the only way I've found is to create a custom binding with a custom formatter. I don't want to do that, so I'm looking for something already implemented. Didn't know about the WebChannelFactory concrete, but I assume it's used behind the scenes by ChannelFactory?

Comment: Please see the [update] part in the question for a clarification of my problem.

Comment: WebChannelFactory<T> is an alternate implementation of ChannelFactory<T> that wires in the UrlTemplate, etc plumbing on the endpoint

Comment: That's also done when using the ChannelFactory<T>, so I'm led to assume ChannelFactory uses some factory to get a concrete factory.. Off topic though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the request and response are in your favorite format.

```
var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel<IRestClient>(); // whatever bindings I'd need for this

    System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior behaviour = new System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior();
    behaviour.DefaultOutgoingRequestFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json;
    behaviour.DefaultOutgoingResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json;
    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(behaviour);
    m_Proxy = client.CreateChannel();


var response = m_Proxy.Authorize("abc", "def", 123);
```